# What are the highest possible drops from Hell Mephisto and Pindleskin?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I picked up D2R again after playing for a while on release, and now that I have a good setup to magic find, I'm torn between two spots, Pindle and Mephisto, but not because of difficulty, rather due to the drop chances. My question is: **What are the highest TC level items they can drop? What is the highest rune they can drop?**

Answer (score 3):

Hell Pindleskin is mlvl 86, and as a superunique monster has a predefined treasure class (tc87). That means his drop table includes every *base* item in the game, and so he can drop every rune in the game. However, since his monster level is 86, he cannot drop any unique or set item with a qlvl of 87+. This means that while he *can* drop unique Sacred Armors, they will never be Tyreal's Might (qlvl 87).

Mephisto is mlvl 87, and (also) as a superunique monster has a predefined treasure class (tc78). His drop table therefore does not include the "best" items, like Hydra Bows (Windforce) or Coronas (Crown of Ages). The highest rune he can drop is Cham. Unlike Pindleskin, he *can* drop Arachnid Mesh, because the base treasure class for Spiderweb Sash is tc63 (less than or equal to his tc) and Arach's qlvl is 87 (less than or equal to his monster level).

If you're targeting a specific item, I recommend using a drop calculator like this one: https://maxroll.gg/d2/d2-drop-calculator